# How to check object is kind of block or not

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

How can we identify any particular object is kind of block or not?

for example,

```
NSSet *set =[NSSet setWithObjects:
             @"name1",
             @"name2",
             [^{ /* ..... some code */ } copy],
             nil];
```

How can we find out which object from set is kind of block?

Answer (score 12):

There is a safer way to determine if something is a block without actually using private api or constructing a class using the private string name:

```
- (BOOL)isBlock:(id)item {
    id block = ^{};
    Class blockClass = [block class];
    while ([blockClass superclass] != [NSObject class]) {
        blockClass = [blockClass superclass];
    }
    return [item isKindOfClass:blockClass];
}
```

Comment: I made this a bit nicer - here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/steipete/6ee378bd7d87f276f6e0

Comment: Can you explain why you're using the block superclass, and not the block class itself?

Comment: @JonathanChen Blocks may have different classes (class cluster), but we can assume that they have a common parent class

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your block in a class of your own:

```
BlockWrapper *blockWrapper = [BlockWrapper wrapperWithBlock:^{ … }];
```

Check for the type and extract the actual block:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[BlockWrapper class]]) {
    codeBlock = [(BlockWrapper*)obj block];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way to do this. You must keep track of what objects are blocks, and what their type signatures are.

Do you have a practical use case for a set of mixed strings and blocks?

Comment: Well, strictly you _can_ check that an object is something other than a block (since a block is not e.g. an `NSString`).  And that _is_ supported.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but I wouldn't recommend doing this, because `NSBlock` is not a public class and its name might change in the future:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSBlock")]) {
    NSLog(@"It's a block!");
}
```

Comment: Your answer should be the right one. Another question, how to check its arguments type and return value type?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have strings and blocks, just check `![thing isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`. i.e. invert your test.

Likewise, if you have strings, numbers and blocks, check that `thing` is not a string or a number, and in that case it must (by deduction) be a block.  Either that, or your program is incorrect and will crash.

Answer (score -3):

I suppose that `![thing isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]`, while not technically correct (you don't have to subclass `NSObject`), will probably get you want you want.

Comment: That won't work. `NSBlock` is derived from `NSObject`. `[NSClassFromString(@"NSBlock") isSubclassOfClass:[NSObject class]]` returns `YES`.